# What does the search flag 'z' do in VIM?

Tags: vim, search

I was looking for a way to show a bit of context around my searches when doing

`g/mysearchtext/p`

When I stumbled across this page [Search-a-pattern-and-provide-a-context-few-lines-above-and-below](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Search-a-pattern-and-provide-a-context-few-lines-above-and-below-td5631241.html) where someone mentions the mysterious (to me) search flag 'z'. As in

`g/cat/z#.3`

My initial research suggests it some sort of 'total number of lines returned per result' but setting it to `z#.2` only shows one line per search result. So I am confused and I'm having trouble finding the docs under `:help pattern`.

So here are my questions:

- What does the `z` flag do?
- How does `#.3` modify it?
- Where in the docs can I find this information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
g/cat/z#.3
```

Let's dissect this. `:help :g` tells you that the last thing is a **command**, not a flag (like those of `:substitute`):

```
:[range]g[lobal]/{pattern}/[cmd]
```

Let's try `:help :z`; voilà:

```
:{range}z[+-^.=]{count} Display several lines of text surrounding the line
                            specified with {range}, or around the current line
                            if there is no {range}.
:{range}z#[+-^.=]{count}
                            Like ":z", but number the lines.
```

So, you'll get a numbered (`#`) printing of `3` lines around (`.`) the current line (that matches `cat`).

Comment: The `z#.2` doesn't work because it addresses 1/2 above / below, and that seems to be rounded down to 1.

Comment: Bah! Good call I definitely spaced on looking through the docs there. I was doing `:help z` (no colon).